# Breaking down model into sql tables issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

and each customer have basic info `(name, age, address)` and can have few solutions that the website offers, currently there is only 1 maybe it will be 2 or 3 in the future (not something that will be big).

the one solution that currently the website offers is:

```
PaymentSolution
```

Now PaymentSolution have its own services:

```
PersonalPaymentService

OfficePaymentService
```

both of those services have `active` parameter that can be `true/false`

and for each service there are 3 payment options that can also be `active` `true/false`

For example:

```
PersonalPaymentService(active true)

paymentType           startPaymentDate(date value)  finishPaymentData(date value)   active(boolean)

apartment payment       1/1/2018                      1/1/2019                      true

car payment             1/1/2018                      1/1/2019                      true

jetSki payment          1/1/2018                      1/1/2019                      false



OfficePaymentService(active false)

paymentType          startPaymentDate(date value)  finishPaymentData(date value)    active(boolean)  contactEmail(string value)

office payment         1/1/2018                      1/1/2019                       true              john@rentOffice.com

computers payment      1/1/2018                      1/1/2019                       false             john@rentComputers.com
```

Im trying to figure out how to model such information structure to sql tables, can someone please offer some directions please?

im having hard time how to break this into the right relations and having this model able to scale to more solutions in the future

queries I want to be able tp perform are something like:

```
give me PersonalPaymentService data for customer id 35.
give me OfficePaymentService for account id 43.
give me all data for customer id 67
```

anything can help! thanks!

Comment: What types of queries do you exect to answer? because the design can change based on the types of queries.

Comment: @RJadhav added to the end of the question

Comment: Age isn't basic info (although date of birth could be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should revisit your design, based on your comment,

> for example give me all PersonalPaymentService data for customer id
>   35. or give me OfficePaymentService for account id 43...or of course give me all data for customer id 67

I think the PersonalPaymentService and OfficePaymentService are logical representation of data and your actual payments are only the 6 types you described.

If you want to keep your tables clean and if you are using your mysql as a datastore, I would say just create a table like

```
CustomerID, PaymentType, StartPaymentDate, EndPaymentDate
```

where the PaymentType belongs to only the 6 subtypes.

and use your logical programming (PHP, Java whatever) to categorize the payments into office and personal types.

The advantage of using this schema is that in future if you decide to introduce another payment type, you will not require any schema changes.

However, if your constraint is that SQL should answer your queries whether its personal or office payment, you could theoretically introduce another type (column) called PaymentCategory, which has personal or office payment.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other post, Creating one table and adding a type discriminator column to that table would be the better approach for now . Also writing queries against one table would be easy . There are some situations when you have to add new types with some data(columns) specific to that  type in your case column like `contactEmail`  and later  you could end up with a table with lot of columns and most of them have null values.

In those type of situations creating a one  table(`PaymentService`) with  common columns  and creating  separate table for each type(`PersonalPayment,OfficePayment etc..` ) then  adding foreign key constraint to maintain one to one relationship with the  common table  and each  type tables could be a better solution.Writing queries against is not easy compare to previous approach and which  requires to join type table  with the common table.

Other option is to create  separate tables for each type.